# Bridge LAN and WAN in OpenWrt client mode

Tags: networking, openwrt

I have just setup a TL-WR841N on client mode. The client router's IP address is 192.168.1.1 while that of host router is 10.0.0.1. There are two Wireless interfaces on the client router one which sets the router as client on the network/interface WWAN (different from WANwhich is for WAN port on the router). The other wireless interface makes it an Access Point on the LAN interface. The setup is working fine as a wireless repeater but I would like to bridge both the interfaces(LAN and WWAN) such that the devices that connect to the client router could get an IP address like 10.0.0.x instead of something like 192.168.1.x. When I try to bridge interfaces from WWAN, everything seems to stop working. The wireless power goes to 0 and it says the wireless isn't associated to any network. How can I achieve what I have tried to explain?

Comment: You can’t just bridge wireless networks. Please read [the corresponding article on the OpenWrt wiki](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/clientmode?s[]=client&s[]=mode) in its entirety. Also, please provide the actual commands you used.

Comment: @DanielB I made these changes using LuCI interface so I don't have the exact commands.